# How to understand: If the query includes both ORDER BY and DISTINCT, the ORDER BY clause cannot include columns not mentioned in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql

My class slide says: If the query includes both ORDER BY and DISTINCT, the ORDER BY clause cannot include columns not mentioned in the SELECT clause.
However, the following query works and returns as expected ([at this website](https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/) if that matters).

```
SELECT distinct age
FROM Customers
order by country
```

So I assume this statement was not complete. How was this statement to be worded?

Comment: What database are you learning? As in Oracle, MySQL etc. Some might not allow this, others might try something like sort on the first country that occurs for the age value.

Comment: The statement is correct and logically how it should be. Probably some DBs such as MariaDB might allow this but really should not. See [how-sql-distinct-and-order-by-are-related](https://blog.jooq.org/how-sql-distinct-and-order-by-are-related/)